# Is it possible to ansynchronously capture canvas image to ensure WebGL canvas isn't currently blank/black during swapping?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, webgl

We are trying to take a snapshot of a video that is playing on a WebGL canvas.  However, when the user clicks the snapshot button the image captured is sometimes black. YES - I have read all of the threads about how the WebGL canvas works with the swapping so I understand why we are getting a black image.  We, unfortunately, cannot set the preserveDrawingBuffer property to true because our video needs to be of the highest quality and cannot afford any slow down.

I would like to see if I could programmatically keep taking snapshots until I get a good image.

The problem is that I can't just use a loop as that blocks the canvas from ever getting a new image drawn to it.  So, if I just added a while loop and kept calling canvas.toDataURL, it would constantly get the same black image because the canvas is never being updated.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to capture the canvas asynchronously so that the canvas is still being updated.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: A while loop blocks. Use `setTimeout` / `setInterval` / `requestAnimationFrame` instead

Answer (score 0):

Just repeating the answers you claim you already read

1. use `preserveDrawingBuffer`

   ```
   const gl = someCanvas.getContext('webgl', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
   ```
2. capture after drawing

   ```
   function render() {
      drawWithWebGL();
      if (needScreenshot) {
        takeScreenshot();
      }
   }
   ```
3. draw before capture (really the same as 2)

   ```
   function doScreenshot() {
     drawWithWebGL();  // force a draw
     takeScreenshot();
   }
   ```

Everything else is some variation of those 3 solutions

So ...

> Is it possible to ansynchronously capture canvas image to ensure WebGL canvas isn't currently blank/black during swapping?

Without `preserveDrawingBufffer` the answer is "no"

Comment: Thanks gman. I'm playing with a hack here to capture a handful of images over a second or so of time in order to give me the best chance of capturing a good image. I can then test the captures for a good image based on the length.  For a blank/black image the length is always quite small.  I have to stagger the captures so that I'm not blocking the canvas from being updated. So, I essentially end up with a handful of calls to the capture function on the call stack and they are going to be executed in a staggered fashion. It isn't perfect but with 10 or so calls I get a good image every time.

Comment: Why hack a unstable solution when the correct way is so easy?

Comment: The video client code (where the drawing is happening to the canvas) is not within our domain and I've been told that they do not want enable preserveDrawingBuffer because it will potentially cause a performance hit and our live stream is used for security purposes.